# Stream internal sound from mac to pc?

Tags: windows, mac, audio

I'm using a headphone connected to a PC, however, I also use a mac. I want to make it so that the internal sound, coming from the mac will also be heard over at the pc. So I want to convert the headphone to a somewhat central sound output where I hear both pc and mac's internal sounds. That includes error alerts, mp3s played on iTunes, etc. Is there an app that will let me do this? Just to clarify, the PC is running Windows XP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [Airfoil for mac](http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) that will send to a PC with Airfoil Speaker for Windows

Comment: It looks like Airfoil Speaker was rebranded to Airfoil Satellite.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is a external audio mixer and feed it with the output of both machines.  Then you plug your headphones into the output/monitor jack.